# Prove that $|a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|$ implies $\{a_n\}$ bounded and convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to prove that every sequence for which

$|a_{n+1}-a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2}|a_{n}-a_{n-1}|$

is true, is bounded and convergent.
I tried defining $b_n = a_n$ and $c_n = a_{n-1}$ and then use Stolz, but it didn't work.

How could I prove this?

Comment: Can you prove that such a sequence is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @CatalinZara I can try. just a moment

Comment: Actually you can prove that for any $0<C<1$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}$ it holds that sequence is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @arberavdullahu I'm not sure I understand how

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1677423/9464

Comment: The sequence is Cauchy. It will be convergent for sure if the sequence is defined in an order complete space like $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the boundedness:

You can write, using the triangle inequality and your assumption,$^{(\dagger)}$ $$
\lvert a_n - a_0 \rvert = \left\lvert\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (a_{k+1}-a_k)\right\rvert
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left\lvert a_{k+1}-a_k\right\rvert
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{k}}\left\lvert a_{1}-a_0\right\rvert
\leq  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}\left\lvert a_{1}-a_0\right\rvert
= 2\left\lvert a_{1}-a_0\right\rvert
$$
so we get $\lvert a_n\rvert \leq \lvert a_n - a_0 \rvert + \lvert a_0\rvert \leq 2\lvert a_1 - a_0 \rvert + \lvert a_0\rvert$ for all $n$.

$(\dagger)$ Indeed, by a straightforward induction we get $\left\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n\right\rvert
\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}\left\lvert a_{1}-a_0\right\rvert$ for all $n\geq 0$.

(for the convergence, the same "trick" but starting the sum at some $m$ (i.e., with $a_m$ instead of $a_0$) will enable you to show the sequence is Cauchy.)

Comment: I'm trying your solution right now

Comment: thank you! I never thought about that 3rd step!

Comment: Glad this helped.

Comment: Actually $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}=2$.

Comment: Darn, indeed. Messing up numbers. (Thanks!)

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not sure I did the 3rd step correctly for the convergence. It's supposed to be $\leq \sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2^k}|a_{m+1}-a_m|$, right?

Comment: (From my phone) yes, this looks believable. Now, take the part that doesn't depend on k out of the sum, and sum what remains - the 1/2^k - from k=m to (upper bound) infinity.

Comment: @ClementC. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Define $c:=|a_1-a_0|\ge 0$. Then by induction $|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|\le \frac{c}{2^n}$, therefore $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence indeed
$$
|x_n-x_m|\le |x_n-x_{n-1}|+|x_{n-1}-x_{n-2}|+\cdots+|x_{m+1}-x_m| \le \frac{c}{2^{m-1}}
$$
for all $n>m$. Then it is enough to choose $m$ sufficiently large so that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try
$$ |a_n|=|a_1+(a_2-a_1)++\cdots+(a_{n-1}-a_{n-2})+(a_n-a_{n-1})|\le|a_1|+|a_2-a_1|+\cdots+|a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}|+|a_n-a_{n-1}|$$