# ${x_n}$ is a sequence such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| \leq \frac{1}{2}|x_n - x_{n-1}|$. Prove $x_n$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

The sequence looks Cauchy. But I do not know how to approach the proof.

Comment: Basically, you have written $1 \leq \dfrac{1}{2}$, which is wrong!

Comment: Nothing  to prove!

Comment: $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are convergent sequences. Therefore, $(x_n)$ is convergent. QED

Comment: I am sorry. I mistyped the question

Comment: Then for each $p \in \mathbb N*$, what could you say about $\vert x_{n+p} - x_n\vert$ ?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2070528/42969